# How can I conditionally sum cells?

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with data like the following:

```
lot amount  code    acct#
------------------------------
1   5       rrec    123456
1   3       rdel    123456
1   4       rrec    567890
1   11      rrec    567890
1   33      rdel    001122
1   44      rdel    001122
1   100     rrec    001122
2   99      rdel    555666
2   21      rdel    555666
2   1       rrec    777777
```

If the code for a line is `rrec` the amount is positive, if it's `rdel` it's negative.

I want to add the amounts by acct# for each lot.

The data above would come out to be:

```
lot total   acct#
----------------------
1   2       123456 
1   15      567890
1   23      001122
2   -120    555666
2   1       777777
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Conditionally as in SUM IF some condition?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this

1. Use VBA to check for rrec or rdel then make the corresponding value positive or negative

Example:

```
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("D1:D10")

For Each cell In rng
     //add if for rrec and rdel here
Next cell
```

2. Use excel built in SUMIFS statement to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in columns A:D, and your output is in columns F:H, you can use this formula for the total in cell G2:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,D:D,"="&H2,C:C,"=rrec") - SUMIFS(B:B,D:D,"="&H2,C:C,"=rdel")
```

Copy down to G6:

[image]